# Symfony2 transchoice tag

Tags: symfony, translation

I have added the translator service for my Symfony2 project. I use it both in controllers and in **twig** templates. It's configured fine and all the `{% trans %}` tags work as they mean to. But in some cases I need to use the `{% transchoice %}` tag, and it's not getting the translation. Here is an example from my code.

```
{% transchoice post['comments']['count'] %}
    {0} Comments| {1} Comment| ]1,Inf] Comments
{% endtranschoice %}
```

Also have tried writing this in one line.

I get the correct choice for the comment count, but the word itself is not beeng translated. Like the translator is not able to find the corresponding translation. In the **messages.de.yml** I have

```
Comment: "Kommentar"
Comments: "Kommentare"
```

Is it something wrong with my transchoice syntax? Maybe I need to place spaces somewhere, or anything like that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your translation file, you should write this:

```
{0} Comments| {1} Comment| ]1,Inf] Comments: "{0} Kommentare| {1} Kommentar| ]1,Inf] Kommentare"
```

**UPDATE:**
An xliff example that works for me :

```
        <trans-unit id="search.results.summary">
            <source>search.results.summary</source>
            <target>{0}Pas d'annotations trouvée pour "%search_text%"|{1}Une annotation trouvée pour "%search_text%"|]1,Inf]%search_count% annotations trouvées pour "%search_text%"</target>
        </trans-unit>
```

How I use it:

```
<h2>{{ 'search.results.summary' | transchoice(search_count, {
'%search_text%': search_text,
'%search_count%': search_count}) }}</h2>
```

As you see, I don't use the complicated notation as the source for my translation, since it is pretty useless and would make the template less readable. Instead, I put a dot-separated string representing the semantical value of my string.

In your case, I guess the correct thing to use would be something like this:

```
comment.summary: "{0} Kommentare|{1} Kommentar|]1,Inf] Kommentare"
```

and

```
{% transchoice post['comments']['count'] %}
    'comment.summary'
{% endtranschoice %}
```

Good luck.

Comment: that won't be correct for translation choice. By the way this can't even be parsed in twig.

Comment: Why do you say this won't be correct? I'm not familiar with yml for translations, but I did use this with xliff, and it works (and parses pretty well). Maybe you'll have to adjust some things. By the way I reused what you wrote, so if it does not parses, it is *your* fault. And I think it does not parse because of the spaces between pipes and brackets. I'll update my post with an xliff example that works for me, I hope it will help you.

Comment: Now that works. The only problem is that in case of missing translation, the `comment.summary` text will be displayed...

Comment: If you have a restricted set of languages and keep in mind that there is a fallback locale defined in your config.yml, this should not be a problem. You can still use the other way if you prefer.